# I am trying to connect my ReactNative app via Expo App to my local express server, but am getting network errors. Any suggestions?

Tags: react-native, express, expo

I am trying to connect my React Native app via Expo App to my local express server, but am getting network errors. I originally was using localhost as the url, then after reading through Stack I realized my errors, and switched it to my computers IP address.

I am on a windows machine using WSL, not sure if that will make a huge difference here.

Any suggestions?

This is my frontend Create User component:

```
import { View, Text, TextInput, Button, Alert } from "react-native";
import { createUserStyle } from "./createUserStyle";
import { homeButtonStyles } from "../Buttons/buttonStyle";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios, { Axios } from "axios";
import UploadImage from "../uploadImage";

// import InitialsAvatar from 'react-initials-avatar';

export default function CreateUser({}) {
  const [user, setUser] = useState("");
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [handicap, setHandicap] = useState(0);

  const fetchApi = async () => {
    try {
      const res = await axios.get("http://192.168.1.79:8080/createUser");
      console.log(res.data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.message);
    }
  };

  const onPressButton = () => {
    // fetchApi();
    console.log('ON PRESS CLICKED');
    const payload = {
      email: email,
      name: name,
      handicap: handicap,
    };

    if(handicap > 20) {
      Alert.alert(' You must enter a valid numerical handicap')
    };
    if (payload) {
      return fetch('http://192.168.1.79:8080/createUser', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          Accept: 'application/json',
          "Content-type": "application/json",
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(payload),
      })
      .then((result) => result.json())
        .then((resultData) => {
          console.log('RESPONSE RECIEVED', JSON.stringify(resultData));
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log('ERRRRRRROR', error)
          Alert.alert('Something went wrong while creating the user.');
        })
    } 
  };

  return (
    <View style={createUserStyle.container}>
      <Text style={{ marginVertical: 16 }}>{"Enter Email"}</Text>
      <TextInput
        style={createUserStyle.textbox}
        onChangeText={(text) => setEmail(text)}
        secureTextEntry={false}
      />
      <Text style={{ marginVertical: 16 }}>
        {name ? `Hi ${name}!` : "Enter Full Name"}
      </Text>
      <TextInput
        style={createUserStyle.textbox}
        onChangeText={(text) => setName(text)}
        secureTextEntry={false}
      />
      <Text style={{ marginVertical: 16 }}>
        {handicap
          ? `You are a ${handicap} handicap, (liar)`
          : "Enter Handicap (NO SANDBAGGING)"}
      </Text>
      <TextInput
        style={createUserStyle.textbox}
        onChangeText={(text) => setHandicap(text)}
        secureTextEntry={false}
      />
      {/* <UploadImage /> */}
      {/* <InitialsAvatar name={name} /> */}
      <View style={homeButtonStyles.container}>
        <Button title="Submit" onPress={onPressButton} />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

The errors I'm getting is: Type Error: Network request failed
This is my backend:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const PORT = 8080; // default port 8080
// const db = require("./db/connection.js");
const cors = require("cors");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Hello!");
});

app.post("/createUser", (req, res) => {
  const { email, name, handicap } = req.body;
  console.log('REQ BODY: ', req.body);

  res.status(200).json({
    message: "User created successfully",
    user: {
      email,
      name,
      handicap
    }})
})

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${PORT}!`);
});
```

Comment: As per mu understanding, as you are using windows wsl, when you start the expo server it's scope will be only inside WSL because of which you can't connect. What is the ip that is getting generated when you run the server? Is it in the formate of 172.x.xx.x or 192.x.xx?

Comment: @Adii_Mathur To be honest, without a client connection, i'm unsure how to get the IP of the server.  If i was connecting I could do something like:
const ipAddress = req.socket.remoteAddress;
    res.send(ipAddress);
So without connection, i'm lost.

Comment: I know this might not be the best solution, but I think you should start the tunnel instead of the local server. This might solve your problem.

Comment: Any chance you came across a solution? Having exact issue myself @ToddTeigland